# Как результат работы модуля PDFMiner поместить в текстовый файл?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

Для извлечения текста из PDF файла, воспользовался модулем **PDFMiner**. В результате в самой консоли, при выполнении кода, сам текст из PDF появляется, а вот записать его после выполнения модуля не получается. В файле появляется одно единственное слово `None`.

Каким образом записать распознанный этим модулем текст в файл?

Вот код:

```
import sys
import pdfminer.high_level # $ pip install pdfminer.six


# Сюда в качестве первого параметра передаётся название файла для распознавания
with open('mail_cir.pdf', 'rb') as file: 
    # Собственно работа самого модуля. Переменной текст присваиваю результат
    # работы модуля и сразу перевожу этот результат в текстовый формат (str)
    text = str (pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(file, sys.stdout)) 
    file2 = open("Текст.txt", "w") # Создаю файл с именем "Текст.txt"  
    file2.write(text) # Записываю в файл результат
```

В ИТОГЕ в файле слово `None`. А должен быть весь распознанный текст из PDF.

Comment: Все работает. Как мне вас поблагодарить на этом портале? Я не нашёл ни возможности оценить ответ ни возможности поставить вам здесь лайк, например.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите `str()` последующие строки. Замените `sys.stdout` на `file2`